# how do you break up echos with php tags?

Tags: php, html, tags, echo

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['value'])){

echo ?>

HTML CODE GOES HERE

<?php
; 
}
?>
```

Can something like this be accomplished? I'm getting red errors from my script.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clear... I wanted all my PHP code at the top block. So I was going to instead of using echo, use a variable to concatenate my codes so I can echo it somewhere in my html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drop the echo and the semi colon and it should work fine.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['value'])){ ?>

HTML CODE GOES HERE

<?php } ?>
```

or you can use this syntax

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['value'])): ?>
    HTML HERE
<?php endif ?>
```

Additionally you could also look into the heredoc syntax for writing strings (your HTML)

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['value'])){
    echo <<<EOT
    HTML GOES HERE
EOT;    
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

drop "echo", it works

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['value'])){
?>
     HTML CODE GOES HERE
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['value'])){ ?>

HTML CODE GOES HERE

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work without the echo, but you could also try this:

```
<?php if isset($_GET['value']): ?>

   HTML CODE GOES HERE

<?php endif; ?>
```